# How do I set an option only if there are multiple windows?

Tags: vim-windows, options

Sometimes when I load several buffers at once into multiple windows I might get confused with the position of the cursor,  I get lost when I change from buffer to buffer.
Therefore I'd like to trigger the ex command `:set cursorline` to be able to easily see the cursor position.

How can I trigger the command when I load two or more buffers into multiple windows but remove it when there's just one window left?

One window:
[image]

Several windows:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try the following autocmd:

```
augroup cursorline
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter * exe winnr('$')>1 ? "set cursorline" : "set nocursorline"
augroup END
```

Whenever you enter a window (`WinEnter` event), it executes the following command:

```
exe winnr('$')>1 ? "set cursorline" : "set nocursorline"
```

The latter tests if there are several windows (`winnr('$')>1`). If that's the case, it enables `'cursorline'`, otherwise it disables it.